# how to update value from another TSQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have to update value based on values from another table:

```
update OracleOb..NS.myTable set name = (select name from myTable1 where id = 1)
   where id = 1
```

here the SQL has some problem. How can I get value from myTable1 and set it to myTable?

I am using MS SQL 2005.

Sorry I have to edit this question again. The table myTable is a linked object of Oracle table. I tried the suggested answer but I got error message:

```
 The OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "OracleOb" reported an error. The provider reported an unexpected catastrophic failure.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
UPDATE m 
SET m.name = m1.name
FROM MyTable m
    JOIN MyTable1 m1 ON m.id = m1.id
WHERE m.id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Remove the where clause if you are trying to update more than just the 1 record.

UPDATE  MyTable
SET     Name = B.Name
FROM    MyTable A JOIN MyTable1 B ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE   ID = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a join like:

```
update myTable 
set name = myTable1.name 
from myTable inner join myTable1 
   on myTable.id = myTable1.id myTable 
      where id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update myTable set 
    name = t1.name
from myTable as t
    join myTable1 as t1 on t.id = t1.id
    where t.id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a update by checking other TWO tables :

UPDATE C SET C.username = A.UserName FROM Staged.ClientEmployee C
            JOIN  [dbo].[TempE] E ON C.id = E.Fax AND C.ssn = E.SSN
            JOIN NW_SEFL.CFG.Account A ON A.EmployeeId = E.EmployeeId 
            WHERE E.Fax = @StageEmpID